# GCP - Terraform - Can't Edit Organization Policies

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I ran the following Org policy accidentally:

```
module "allowed_policy_member_domains_org_policy" {
  source     = "terraform-google-modules/org-policy/google"
  policy_for = "organization"

  constraint      = "constraints/iam.allowedPolicyMemberDomains"
  policy_type     = "list"
  organization_id = data.google_organization.org.org_id
  allow           = var.allowed_policy_member_domains
  enforce         = true
}
```

where I accidentally included the enforce, which looks to have locked me out of my organization policies. I am an owner on my account, but when I go to the org policies page, the Edit button is grayed out.

I went to try and add ANY roles to anybody, and now I can't do that:

[can't add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYAfK.png)

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

1. Create a VM where your terraform SA lives, and make sure to use that SA as the service account
2. run `cloud beta resource-manager org-policies delete iam.allowedPolicyMemberDomains --organization [YOUR_ORG_ID]`

Should work!

Comment: Also note the reason I had to go the VM way was because i disabled service account key creation as well ;)